# imacro on tumblr posts for adding multiple tags

Tags: imacros

I have been using iMacros to input multiple tags when posting photos to save time. They have recently updated the site and I can not figure out how to get iMacro to enter multiple tags.

When recording a macro this is the code iMacro comes up with

`TAG POS=11 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=* CONTENT=foo,`

The `,` is needed to start a new tag. It is not starting a new tag or recording the content correctly.

I have looked at the code where the tags come up and this is it below

```
<section class="tag_editor" style="display: block;">
<div class="tags">
<input class="post_tags" type="text" value="" style="display: none;" name="post[tags]">
<div class="editor_wrapper">
<input class="editor borderless" type="text">
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

It looks like the input I need is around `editor_wrapper` and `editor borderless` and I think I need it added to `FORM=NAME:NoFormName` and `ATTR=*` in the iMacro `TAG`. I have tried different combinations yet iMacro will not autofill the tags for me. The new post feature on tumblr is a pop-up ajax looking window.

The old macro that worked before the site update looked like this. Not sure if it will be of any help.

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ACTION:/blog/foobar/new/photo ATTR=ID:tag_editor_input CONTENT=foo,
WAIT SECONDS=.3
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ACTION:/blog/foobar/new/photo ATTR=ID:tag_editor_input CONTENT=bar,
WAIT SECONDS=.3
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ACTION:/blog/foobar/new/photo ATTR=ID:tag_editor_input CONTENT=foo,
```

Looking for help getting this to work again. It saves me a ton of time to have these tags auto filled for me.

Answer (score 0):

try this one to fill the second input:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=CLASS:editor* CONTENT=foo,
```

let me know if it works